# I want to find out how many new members I have using MySQL for the registration year 2017

Tags: mysql, count, members

My columns are Year and AthleteID. Every time someone registers they keep the same AthleteID, so A query that returns all members from all years would look like the below:

```
|AthleteID | Year|
| 1234     | 2016|
| 1234     | 2017|
| 3243     | 2016|
| 0134     | 2015|
| 4567     | 2017|
| 5678     | 2017|
| 1234     | 2017|
```

I want to return just new member in 2017 so in the example above it would return only the below:

```
|AthleteID|| Year|
| 4567     | 2017|
| 5678     | 2017|
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your attempt.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help.

Comment: and see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, you have a duplicate entry, which begs the question: what's your PRIMARY KEY?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the minimum year for each athlete, and then filter the new users with a `HAVING` clause.

Like so:

```
SELECT AthleteID,
       min(YEAR)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY AthleteID
HAVING min(YEAR) = 2017
```